# syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE in pagination.php

Tags: joomla

When going to the website I get the following error:

> syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE in /libraries/joomla/pagination/pagination.php on line 701

The line 701 is as follows:

```
$data->end->link = JRoute::_($params . '&' . $this->prefix . 'limitstart
```

Comment: The problem is not coming from the pagination.php in the library folder, it will most likely be coming from the pagination.php in your template folder. Can you provide the code from there please?

Comment: Is that really the full line?! Are there any lines after it? Because that line should read more like `$data->end->link = JRoute::_($params . '&' . $this->prefix . 'limitstart=' . $end);`. If this isn't the full line, then you likely have corrupted core files and you should redownload your version of Joomla and copy the files over the copy of your install to make sure that they all match.